# Do I need to dump databases from a volume before backing them up?

Tags: database, docker, mariadb, backup, docker-volume

There are plenty of resources on *how* to dump Postgres/Mariadb/MySQL/etc. databases from a volume/container; my question is if I *need* to do so before backing them up. More explicitly, is it safe to stop my MariaDB container, copy the contents of the volume to another folder, and back that up directly? Are there consequences I should be aware of?
My current export code:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/backup/mariadb_backup
docker run --rm -v mariadb_volume:/data -v $HOME/backup:/backup ubuntu cp -aruT /data /backup/mariadb_backup
```

I then run borg on the backup folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to back up the files of a stopped database.

People usually don't want to shut down a database that's providing some service, so they come up with methods how not to do that.

One is run a dump operation that exports the contents of a database while it is serving other requests.

Another is a filesystem snapshot. That is atomically take a snapshot of the files underlying the database so that all files retain their content from a single point in time and then back that up.

The only thing you should not do is back up the files of a running database one by one. You will get an inconsistent copy if you do that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize dump operations were a way to avoid shutting the database down. I'm just running this on a homeserver and I've set it up to shut down all my containers before a backup anyways, so it sounds like for my use-case, backing up the entire volume is suitable. Thanks!